# How to test the case that HTML <object> (or a similar feature) is unsupported?

Tags: html, testing, browser

I'm writing a web page that has a HTML `<object>` in it, like

```
<object [...]>Your browser does not support this.</object>
```

On all my machines I only have up-to-date browsers installed and don't want to clutter my machines with old browsers (this is actually not easily possible in most cases without depending on third-party-software and/or doing hours of configuration tweaking).

I know of pages like https://www.browserstack.com/ that let you render websites, but this is rather time consuming when I frequently need to check loads of small changes. And honestly I actually don't want to give my data to external companies just for a simple rendering.

How can I easily check how my page would look on old browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it out. The content between the `<object></object>` tags is not only triggered in unsupporting browsers, but also when the `data` attribute holds an invalid target (like an unavailable file).

So, to test how it looks on unsupporting browsers, one can simply set the `data`-attribute to something unavailable. But keep in mind that the webdesigner then also has to define a more meaningful message than just "Your browser does not support SVG", but also has to consider that the object to display is simply missing (for example in a dynamic setting of the data attribute via PHP, like `data=<?php echo getFile(); ?>` when the function returns something undefined).